# Interpretation of results of logistic regression (Analysis of effects vs Maximum Likelihood Estimates)

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, maximum-likelihood, sas, contrasts

I have ran a logistic regression on my data in SAS.

I get in the results a "Type 3 Analysis of Effects" which gives me a probability for my variables including a categorical variable. The probability of the results being greater than Chi-Square is less than 0.0001%, so this independent variable seems to be correlated with the dependent variable.

I used a orthogonal-contrast coding for this variable, because I wanted to compare the results of any level to the mean, to find the levels that are significantly outside the norm, and not to some arbitrary value of the data (like reference coding would).

But in the analysis of maximum likelihood estimates, none of the levels have a probability being greater than Chi-Square under 0.8%.

I'm somewhat perplex. My interpretation is that the variable as a whole is significant, but not any level in particular. Is this exact?

Also, how do I "decode" the variable back to get the results for the original variable? Is it possible that when I decode the value that some could be significant?

Comment: After using a proc genmod instead of proc logistic, most of my levels became significant because of a smaller standard error, but I still don't know how to decode the orthogonal coding back into actual levels.